# HTML table with whitespace nowrap

Tags: html, css

Hey I was wondering if you can have a HTML table and make certain columns have      `whitespace: nowrap` and the other columns that have `whitespace: normal`?

Example:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No wrap</th>
            <th>Wrap</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Small text</td>
            <td>Wrap this longgggg text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could give an example..

Answer (score 0):

[CSS white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) is `normal` by default, so all you need is to set it to `nowrap` for some of the columns. One way is to add a class to them, as:

```
<td class="my_nowrap">this won't wrap</td>
<style>
.my_nowrap {
     white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>
```

Other way would be to use [CSS3 nth-child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) and (without setting classes) target some of the columns, as:

```
<style>
td:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(3) {
.my_nowrap {
     white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>
```

The above would set 2nd and 3rd column to `nowrap`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. Take a look at the example below.

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}

tr.wrap {
    width: 50px;

}

th.wrap, td.wrap {
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th class='wrap'>Name</th>
    <th colspan="2">Telephone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='wrap'>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>555 77 854</td>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```